# Disable ALL Mate Animations in Ubuntu Mate 20.04

Tags: command-line, 20.04

I am totally blind and using Ubuntu Mate 20.04. How can I disable ALL visual animations or effects for maximum performance?

I have read the following command, but not sure if it works on Mate without Gnome and not sure if it removes all animations.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface enable-animations false
```

Would preferably like a terminal command to accomplish this.

Comment: How much do you expect it to improve?

Comment: I don’t care if it’s only 20 milliseconds. If it is a pointless feature (for me), then no reason to have it. My theory is that many small tweaks like this will add up to a noticeable improvement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Mate there is another setting:

```
gsettings set org.mate.Marco.general reduced-resources false
```

(Marco is the MATE window manager so you need another tree in gsettings).